# How to make an apple script run terminal command on startup on a mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, startup

I am new at this, so I haven't been able to make heads or tails when reading other posts that are similar questions.

I am trying to run a terminal command on startup, then close the terminal.

What I'm trying to run:
cd /Applications/Sick-Beard-development [enter]
python sickbeard.py -d [enter]

I am open to other solutions

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use an AppleScript to run the Terminal to run a shell script to run a Python script instead of, say, just running a Python script in the first place?

Comment: No, not at all, just not sure how to do it... as long as I can have it run in the background

Comment: Also, does it actually have to be _at startup_, or can it be _at login_ for your normal user account?

Comment: it could be at login... since I have to log in every time I boot... never thought of them being different.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to do this is to get all the unnecessary stuff out of the way.

What you want to do is run a Python script at startup. You don't want to see it in a terminal window or anything, so there's no need to get Terminal.app involved. The only reason you've got a shell script involved is to set the working directory, and there are better ways to do that. And presumably the only reason you've dragged in AppleScript was for Terminal.

What you want to do is run your Python script as a launch agent. Apple's documentation on this may be a bit confusing for a novice, but there are some great blog posts around, like [this one by Nathan Grigg](http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/).

The idea is that you create a plist file (either by editing the XML format by hand, or by using one of the plist editors that come with OS X and/or Xcode, or by using a third-party tool like Lingon) that tells OS X "when these conditions are true, run this command, in that working directory". Then you put that file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents. Then you tell `launchctl` to load it. And you're done.

Your plist will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.user3159170.sickbeard</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Applications/Sick-Beard-development/sickbeard.py</string>
        <string>-d</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Applications/Sick-Beard-development/</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true />
</dict>
</plist>
```

These settings will make sure that OS X runs the program when you first load the Launch Agent, and again the first time you login after each subsequent reboot, and no other times, which I think is what you want. But `man launchd.plist` will give you the details of all the options (or, again, read the linked blog post and search for others).

Save this as ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.user3159170.sickbeard.plist.

Now, at the terminal, do this:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.user3159170.sickbeard.plist
```

You may want to look at your Console.log to see what happens. You can try starting and stopping it manually (`man launchctl` will explain how, but basically it's just `launchctl start org.user3159170.sickbeard`). Run `launchctl list` to make sure it's showing up. Once it looks like it's all working, reboot your machine, log in, and make sure it ran again. If it did, you're done.

Comment: my goodness, this is an amazing answer, but alas, it is beyond me.  I think that's why I was trying to get applescript and terminal... I understand: python sickbeard.py -d....  seems like it should be an easy thing, but i'm finding out different.

Comment: @user3159170: Did you read the blog post I linked? Did you look at the [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) tool he recommended? If you don't want to figure all this stuff out for yourself, it may be worth $5 to get a program that just writes, configures, and installs the plist file for you.

Comment: I did... I found something that is simple enough for me, gave it a whirl and it works:
Open Automator and choose a new Workflow
Add a ‘Run Shell Script’ action
Add to following script in the textbox: “/usr/local/bin/python /path/to/sickbeard/sickbeard.py -d”
Save the workflow as an Application in the SickBeard application folder
Goto System Preferences > Accounts > User > Login Items
Add the Application you just created with Automator

Comment: everything that @abarnert described works, except my script is supposed to run as a service (i'm using reactor form twisted.internet library to start several threads) but it exits - all the threads get closed. if i run the file from a command line - everything works fine. any ideas on that?